# I am doing a project on object without monitor and i choosen ststemd for that and i am getting error

Tags: systemd

```
[Unit]
Description=object
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/raspberry_pi/test.py
Restart=always
User=pi
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the code. When I manually start this and look into status i get this

```
● object.service - object
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/object.service; enabled; vendor preset>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-02-22 16:18:40 IST; 8s a>
    Process: 2170 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/raspberry_pi/test.py (cod>
   Main PID: 2170 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 1.520s

Feb 22 16:18:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: object.service: Consumed 1.520s CPU tim>
Feb 22 16:18:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: object.service: Scheduled restart job, >
Feb 22 16:18:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped object.
Feb 22 16:18:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: object.service: Consumed 1.520s CPU tim>
Feb 22 16:18:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: object.service: Start request repeated >
Feb 22 16:18:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: object.service: Failed with result 'exi>
Feb 22 16:18:40 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start object.
```

Please advice somthing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I feel like the error message got cut off somewhere?

Comment: So much information lacking.  What happens if you run `/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/raspberry_pi/test.py` directly?